# how to change layout with orientation change?

Tags: android, orientation

I am changing the layout depending on orientation of phone like this:

onCreate... ->

```
 if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
         }else{

            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
         }
```

this works fine - because onCreate gets called every time when I change orientation of phone - but I want to change layout even with no recall of onCreate - how can I fix that?

i tried with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" - then onCreate it's not reload every time when phone orientation changes, but here i can't controle the layout... what would be the best solution for my question?

EDIT:

I also tried it with adding

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
         }else{

            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
         }


}
```

but here I get an error, when changing orientation

Comment: Have you tried `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)`?

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` from your manifest. Add a folder in your `res/` called `layout-land` and put there the layout you want to show in landscape. Android will pick the right one

Comment: I did it, but there is also the problem with reloading onCreate when I change orientation, i don't want to reload onCreate. layout shall change without reloading oncreate

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do that,
just create a new folder in res folder with name "layout-land" and put your XML there.
when the device screen gets rotated it will automatically fetch the landscape layout from this folder and render it.

Comment: I did it, but there is also the problem with reloading onCreate when I change orientation, i don't want to reload onCreate

Comment: add the android:configChanges="orientation" in your <activity> of manifest.

Comment: my config is  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"

still reloads oncreate when rotating  phone

Comment: or another question, when I did that what you said, what I have to write into my activity? do I only setContentView PORTRAIT?

Comment: does it play any role how my main.xml is named? which one I have to declare in my setContentView? or could you explain it to me like my code above, which part I have to change or delete?

Comment: remove the onConfigChange method and than try it.
see this method will get called every time the screen of you device gets rotated.

Comment: but oncreate is still recalled when i Change Orientation